# css animation duration doesn't seem to matter

Tags: css-animations

I want this element, bluebag, to disappear after a delay, then reappear after a delay. It is doing those things, but I want the reappearance to happen at a later time. No matter what I set my animation-duration to, though, the reappearance is not happening later. Can anyone tell me please what I'm doing wrong?

```css
.anim-object {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    height: auto;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.bluebag {
  opacity: 1; 
  animation-name: opacityOff;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-duration: 100s; /* doesn't seem to matter what I put here */
  animation-delay: 5s;

}
.iteration-1 {
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
.speed-7 {
    animation-duration: 7s
}
@keyframes opacityOff {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
  99% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<img class="anim-object bluebag iteration-1 speed-7 " src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `animation-duration` property is always set to `7s` because you are overriding it on the `speed-7` classname.

Change this value or remove that classname to make it work with `100s`

In the other case, your `animation-iteration` is set to execute once, so in the first iteration the animation will end. You must to put `infinite` to allow animation to execute endless.

Regards.

Comment: Augh! Thank you for catching that!

Comment: You're welcome @LauraNMS , remember to upvote and accept as valid answer when you can.